# Conformal diffeomorphism of higher dimensional unit ball

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I have read one lecture note regarding the conformal diffeomorphism of hypersphere, they construct following conformal map:
$$f=\phi_p^{-1}\circ D_t\circ \phi_p$$
where $\phi_p$ is the steregraphic projection w.r.t point $p\in \mathbb{S}^{n}$, $D_t$ is the dilation map on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I think I understand this map, it maps a domain of sphere to Euclidean space, then dilate it, finally pull it back. It's pushing all the points of sphere to point $p$ expect $-p$. And it is conformal map because it is composition of conformal maps.  Now I am wondering what is the conformal diffeomorphism group of unit ball? Or is there any specific conformal diffeomorphism of unit ball except those trivial ones. I know it has something to do with liouville's theorem, but I couldn't find an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B^{n}$ be the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $S^{n-1}$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, so that $S^{n-1} = \partial B^{n}$.

The conformal automorphisms of $S^{n-1}$ are the Möbius transformations of $S^{n-1}$, *i.e.*, finite compositions of [sphere inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_in_a_sphere) in $\overline{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}}$ if you identify $S^{n-1} \approx \overline{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}}$ by stereographic projection. The conformal map you mention in your question is an example of Möbius transformation.

On the other hand, you can consider Möbius transformations of $\overline{\mathbb{R}^{n}}$ which preserves $B^n$, i.e. finite composition of inversions with respect to spheres that are orthogonal to $\partial B^n$. It turns out that they are the same as the previous ones: they also preserve $\partial B^n = S^{n-1}$ so induce a conformal automorphism of $S^{n-1}$, and all of them are obtained this way. Moreover, they are also all the conformal automorphisms of $B^{n}$.

Note: If you equip $B^{n}$ with the Poincaré metric $g$, *i.e.* the unique complete conformal Riemannian metric in $B^{n}$ of constant curvature $-1$, you obtain the [Poincaré ball model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model) of hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^n$. It turns out that $G$ is also the group of isometries of $\mathbb{H}^n = (B^n, g)$.

In conclusion:
$$G = \mathrm{Aut}(B^{n}) = \mathrm{Möb}(B^{n}) = \mathrm{Möb}(S^{n-1}) = \mathrm{Aut}(S^{n-1}) = \mathrm{Isom}(\mathbb{H}^{n})$$

As a Lie group, $G$ is identified to the Lorentz group $O^+(n,1)$ via the [hyperboloid model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid_model) of $\mathbb{H}^n$ (obtained via another stereographic projection).

I haven't proven anything, so you would need to work or do some research if you want the proofs. But none of it is actually hard to prove.

Comment: @ Seub, thank you so much. I understand most of what you said except that "they are also all the conformal automorphisms of $B^n$", do you mean any conformal automorphism of $B^n$ is constructed as above? Can we have a base conformal map so that every conformal automorphism of $B^n$ is a composition of this map and orthogonal transformation? Because I remember that there exists a conformal map of $S^n$ such that all the conformal map of $S^n$ is the composition of this map and orthogonal transformation of $S^n$.

Comment: The answer to the first question is yes. For the second question, the answer would be yes if what you wrote for $S^n$ is true, since the conformal/orthogonal transformations of $B^n$ are the conformal/orthogonal transformations of $S^{n-1}$. However I think what you wrote for $S^n$ is false. I'm not completely sure but I'll think more about it if you want.

Comment: @ Seub, the fact I mentioned comes from the paper "minimal immersions of surfaces by the first eigenfunctions and confromal area", you can take a look at first paragraph in its Preliminaries. Maybe I misunderstood their statement.

Comment: @ Seub, Actually I haven't figured out what the map constructed in that paper is, but it seems not the inversion you mention. So I guess the base conformal map exists but is hard to find.

Comment: I see, so your misunderstanding is just that in this paper, when they write that any element of $G$ is of the form $T \circ g$, the map $g$ is not fixed: it depends on the element of $G$ that you start with.

Comment: @ Seub, you are right, the map $g$ depends on the point chosen, but it seems that map $g$ there is not the inversion you mentioned (it is so different from one constructed in your way), that's what I am struggling with.

Comment: Well that's not easy to see, because the expression of $g$ they give is only for points in $S^n$. So you'd have to use stereographic projection to see $g$ as a transformation of $R^n$, and then try to see that it's a product of sphere inversions (not necessarily one: it can be a finite product, probably 2).